# angular create formarray instances based on mysql records

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have some records in mysql database. I want to add formcontrols in formarray based on mysql rows. If I pass my mysql success data, I get error as "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined". If I pass static object to formarray, then code works well.

I logged flour_list in console on ngOnInit. But I got response as undefined in console.log.

My ts file code is as below

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grain-flour-list',
  templateUrl: './grain-flour-list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grain-flour-list.page.scss'],
})
export class GrainFlourListPage implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  packagesArray: FormArray;
  sampledata
  add_cart_data
  flour_list
  id
  price
  temp_quantity
  product_id
  quantity
  category_id
  Flours_list
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fb: FormBuilder,
    public route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router, public authservice: AuthService) {


    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.category_id = params.id;

        this.authservice.flour_list(this.category_id).subscribe((data) => {
          this.Flours_list = data
          this.flour_list = this.Flours_list.data

        })
      })



  }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.form = new FormGroup({

      sections: new FormArray(this.flour_list.map(item => {
        const group = this.initSection();
        group.patchValue(item);
        return group;
      }))
    });

  }

  initSection() {
    return new FormGroup({
      category_id: new FormControl(''),
      price: new FormControl(''),
      name: new FormControl('')

    });
  }

  onEventSubmit() { }




  getSections(form) {
    return form.controls.sections.controls;
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be, the data for *flour_list* comes only after your pages is rendered. That is `ngOnInit()` is executed and the *Form* and *FormArray* gets initialised as soon as the page is loaded and then only the data is being assigned to *flour_list*.

You can try, calling the *authservice* inside `ngOnInit()` and initialise the the *Form* inside the `subscribe()` function, like below:

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grain-flour-list',
  templateUrl: './grain-flour-list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grain-flour-list.page.scss'],
})
export class GrainFlourListPage implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  packagesArray: FormArray;
  sampledata
  add_cart_data
  flour_list
  id
  price
  temp_quantity
  product_id
  quantity
  category_id
  Flours_list
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fb: FormBuilder,
    public route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router, public authservice: AuthService) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.category_id = params.id;

        this.authservice.flour_list(this.category_id).subscribe((data) => {
          this.Flours_list = data
          this.flour_list = this.Flours_list.data

          this.form = new FormGroup({

            sections: new FormArray(this.flour_list.map(item => {
              const group = this.initSection();
              group.patchValue(item);
              return group;
            }))
          });

        })
      })


  }

  initSection() {
    return new FormGroup({
      category_id: new FormControl(''),
      price: new FormControl(''),
      name: new FormControl('')

    });
  }

  onEventSubmit() { }




  getSections(form) {
    return form.controls.sections.controls;
  }



}
```

Comment: Not working. Getting error as "Uncaught (in promise): Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in."

Comment: @AmeyKulkarni This error may be with your `HTML` code. Could you please check whether you have added formgroup instance before you are accessing the form controls in your HTML page. Like: `<form [formGroup]="form"> **YourCodeHere** </form>`